# Pine script : Add Plot circle when cross MACD

Tags: pine-script

I use the basic MACD

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="MACD", shorttitle="MACD", timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
// Getting inputs
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", defval=close)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
// Plot colors
col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? 
col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))
plot(macd, title="MACD", color=col_macd)
plot(signal, title="Signal", color=col_signal)
```

I want to add circle when the line cross and i try this but "could not find the function reference 'Cross' "

```
plot(cross(signal, macd) ? signal : na, color=black, style = circles, linewidth = 4)
```

Where is my error please.

Thanks by advance for your help.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pine V5 it is [ta.cross()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dcross).

```
plot(ta.cross(signal, macd) ? signal : na, color= color.black, style = plot.style_circles, linewidth = 4)
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Perfect.  Have a good day